# How pass arguments via require to material avatar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, require, avatar

```
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
```

This code works:

```
<Avatar alt="user 4" src={require('Assets/img/user-1.jpg')} className="size-80 rounded-circle border-info rct-notify" />
```

But I need to pass variable, this code doesn't work :

```
{line.icon != null && <Avatar alt="user 3" src={require(line.icon)} className="size-80 rounded-circle border-warning rct-notify" />}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'Assets/img/user-3.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find some case how it works, but still not enough.

This code works only if in require we start from some text and after this, we can use a variable.

```
{line.icon != null && <Avatar alt="user 3" src={require(`Assets/img/${line.icon}`)} className="size-80 rounded-circle border-warning rct-notify" />}
```